# How to check the number of shares of an url on Google+?

Tags: google-plus

Is there a way to check how many shares of url is done on Google+?

The equivalent from Facebook and Twitter would be: 
http://graph.facebook.com/http://stackoverflow.com
and 
http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://stackoverflow.com

Is there an equivalent on Google+?

Answer (score 7):

Are you looking for this?

https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/fastbutton?url=http://stackoverflow.com

If you are searching for the text value, you can search the following line in the source code of the url:

```
<div id="aggregateCount" class="Oy">{NUMBER_OF_SHARES}</div>
```

The following JavaScript will extract the number of shares from the url:

```
parseInt(document.getElementById('aggregateCount').innerHTML.replace('.',''))
```

Comment: Thanks! Does it apply to the other "Share Link" format? Basically I want to know the count for how many people click "Share" on this overlay:https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://developers.google.com/%2B/  This overlay is invoked by clicking on a G+ icon like this https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/gplus-32.png

Comment: This tells you how many people +1'd a link.  Not the number of shares.